# How can I move items without hardcoded variables

Tags: shell, powershell

I want to move items with the *.txt* extension but not like this, hard-coded. I want to select from a folder all files with some extension and move them into a folder with the same name as extension. And I want to do that for all the extensions in the directory.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Take a look at my code but I did it with hardcoded variables

```
$variable=Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\somePath"

foreach ($variables in $variable)
{

   if($extension=($variables | Where {$_.extension -like ".txt"}))
   {

        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\somePath\text"
        $extension | Move-Item -Destination "C:\somePath\text"
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't think I understand it fully. Are u trying to use a variable for the path? Perhaps you are looking for `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` ?

Comment: What part do you not want hard coded? Do you want it as a command?

Comment: The part with the extensions name. For example, if I have more files with the same extension or with different extension in the main folder I want to put them in specific folders for each extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this solution is not as clean-looking as the other solution, it does handle the case where the destination folders don't already exist. It also moves files that may contain special characters like `[]`. It also explicitly ignores files with no extension since no requirement was given for those. The amount of looping is minimized through the use of `Group-Object`.

```
$Path = "C:\Somepath"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File |
    Group-Object -Property {($_.extension |
        Select-String -Pattern "[^. ]+").matches.value
    }
Foreach ($ExtGroup in $files) {
    $Destination = "$Path\$($ExtGroup.Name)"
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $Destination -PathType Container)) {
        $null = New-Item -Path $Destination -Type Directory
    }
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $ExtGroup.Group -Destination $Destination -Force
}
```

Comment: I tried this, it's working 90%, it creates the folders but doesn't move the items into that specific folder. Thank you for your efforts! LaterEdit: I changed the last line to  $ExtGroup.Group | Move-Item -Destination $Destination -Force and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do:

```
$variable = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\somePath"
foreach ($v in $variable){
$dest = '{0}\{1}' -f  $v.DirectoryName, ($v.Extension -replace '^\.')
$v  | Move-Item -Destination $dest -Force
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's working. If I have two or more files with the same extension this code will transform those files into one and I don't want that

Comment: Only if the files have the same name as well. The extension is just used for the name of the sub-folder. If your files have the same base names, you could consider renaming them with a datestamp.

The -force switch takes care of the cases, where the folder does not exist (ie. the first txt file etc.)